# how to force zip to dowload without temp file?

Tags: php, laravel, public, php-ziparchive, tmp

i want to make dynamic zip, so when admin click .zip, it will download and zip all files in folder based on user ud
user will have document and store on folder with their id

i.e /public/stroage/file/ID001, so when user click button download it will force to download ID0001.zip

here is my code

```html
   $zip = new \ZipArchive();

 $uploaddir = public_path().'/temp'; 

        $tmp_file = tempnam($uploaddir,'');
        $zip->open($tmp_file, \ZipArchive::CREATE);
             
         // Loop through each file
                foreach($files as $file){
                     $url2 = $url.$file->upload;
                     $url2 = str_replace(' ', '%20', $url2);

                        if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
                            die('CURL is not installed!');
                        }

                     $ch = curl_init();
                     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
                     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                     $output = curl_exec($ch);
                     curl_close($ch);
                     $download_file = $output;

                     $type = substr($url2, -5, 5); 
                     #add it to the zip
                     $zip->addFromString(basename($url.$file->upload.'.'.$type),$download_file);
                }
                // close zip
                $zip->close();
            

        
                // Set Time Download
                date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
                $time_name = date('Ymd');
                $time_download = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $log_download = new Log_download;
                
                $user = Auth::user();
                $id_user =  $user->id;
                $log_download->id_praapplication   =  $id_pra;
                $log_download->id_user   =  $id_user;
                $log_download->Activity   =  'Download ZIP File';
                $log_download->type   =  'Zip Archive';
                $log_download->downloaded_at   =  $time_download;
                $log_download->save();
                
                # send the file to the browser as a download
               ob_start();
               $strFile = file_get_contents($tmp_file);         

                header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=DOC-'.$id_pra.'-'.'.zip');
                header('Content-type: application/zip');
                  echo $tmp_file;
                  while (ob_get_level()) {
                    ob_end_clean();
                  }
                  readfile($tmp_file);  

                //$filetopath=$public_dir.'/'.$zipFileName;
               //$filetopath = public_path().'/storage/uploads/file/'. $id_pra.'/'.$zipFileName;
                    // Create Download Response
                   // if(file_exists($filetopath)){
                       // return response()->download($filetopath,$zipFileName,$headers);
                    //} 
                exit;
```

actually this code work. but every utton to dowload zip i clicked, will create a temporary file inside folder /public.
how to download zip without creating temp file or can i make a folder like /public/tmp and save all temp zip to that folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do `$zip->open('php://output', \ZipArchive::CREATE);`. Complete code:

```
   header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=DOC-'.$id_pra.'-'.'.zip');
   header('Content-type: application/zip');
   $zip = new \ZipArchive();
   $zip->open('php://output', \ZipArchive::CREATE);
             
   // Loop through each file
   foreach($files as $file){
      $url2 = $url.$file->upload;
      $url2 = str_replace(' ', '%20', $url2);

      if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
      die('CURL is not installed!');
   }

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $output = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   $download_file = $output;
   $type = substr($url2, -5, 5); 
   #add it to the zip
   $zip->addFromString(basename($url.$file->upload.'.'.$type),$download_file);
}
// close zip
$zip->close();
            

        
// Set Time Download
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
$time_name = date('Ymd');
$time_download = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$log_download = new Log_download;
                
$user = Auth::user();
$id_user =  $user->id;
$log_download->id_praapplication   =  $id_pra;
$log_download->id_user   =  $id_user;
$log_download->Activity   =  'Download ZIP File';
$log_download->type   =  'Zip Archive';
$log_download->downloaded_at   =  $time_download;
$log_download->save();

exit;
```

However, the zip filesize should not exceed the PHP max memory limit. If it does, you'll end up with corrupted zip files.